# How to PUT data onto an elasticsearch datastore nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I've just built out my first elasticsearch datastore using the documentation and that was great. I've also set myself up a lambda to make PUT and GET calls to the elasticsearch datastore but having read multiple resources, I'm still unclear as to how to to connect my lambda up to the elasticsearch to PUT data onto it.

Comment: How is your lambda triggered?
When you put log files in s3, then do s3 triggers the lambda function?

Comment: I've got a lambda behind a sharedgateway. So both the lambda and the elasticsearch datastore are inside the same vpc for more fine grained control. The lambda is triggered through a UI when trying to get or put information